# Making a basic TLV parser in Kaitai

Tags: tlv, kaitai-struct

I can't figure out how to write a simple TLV definition in Kaitai Struct.

I reduced the problem to a simple TLV file where the following repeats until the end of file:

- One byte for the tag
- One byte for the lenght, in bytes
- That many bytes

This definition:

```
meta:
  id: basictlv
  endian: le
types:
  bunch_of_ones:
    seq:
      - id: how_many_1
        type: u1
      - id: ones
        size: how_many_1
  bunch_of_twos:
    seq:
      - id: how_many_2
        type: u1
      - id: twos
        size: how_many_2
seq:
  - id: type_tag
    type: u1
  - id: body
    type:
      switch-on: type_tag
      cases:
        1: bunch_of_ones
        2: bunch_of_twos
```

Used on this file

```
$ xxd simple-tlv-file.dat
00000000: 0102 0101 0203 0202 0203 0103            ............
```

Switches on the type, but it only parse the first TLV and does not repeat.

```
$ ksdump simple-tlv-file.dat sample-tlv.yaml 2> /dev/null
body:
  how_many_1: 2
  ones: 01 01
type_tag: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse a basic TLV with Kaitai Struct, you must break down all the possibilities as `types`, and in your main sequence (aka `seq`) you read the top level "object" until `eos` (or some other mean to mark its end). This way, you can also add a header or other data in the file before the actual TLV structure.

So in your example, move the TLV block to the `types` section:

```
types:
  block_of_data:
    seq:
    - id: type_tag
      type: u1
    - id: body
      type:
        switch-on: type_tag
        cases:
          1: bunch_of_ones
          2: bunch_of_twos
```

You can also add another type, like a header to the `types` section

```
  hello_header:
    seq:
      - id: magic
        contents:
          - 0x48
          - 0x45
          - 0x4C
          - 0x4C
          - 0x4F
```

And you will be able to parse this file:

```
$ xxd ~/downloads/simple-tlv-file.dat
00000000: 4845 4c4c 4f02 0101 0203 0202 0201 0201  HELLO...........
00000010: 01
```

With a main `seq` like this one:

```
seq:
  - id: header
    type: hello_header
  - id: data
    type: block_of_data
    repeat: eos
```